# Do tenses in conditional sentences conflict with the verb tenses in a sentence?

Tags: grammar, tenses, conditionals, past-perfect

OK, we all know that **“The Past Perfect expresses the idea that something occurred before another action in the past.”** [Source](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/pastperfect.html)

Example 1.

> Mary had studied English before she moved to New York.

— **had studied** happened before **moved**.

Now, we also have [conditional sentence Type 3](http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/third-conditional.html) which expresses **“Things that didn't happen in the past”** using the following structure:

If + Past Perfect + Subject + would  have + Past Participle

Example 2:

> *If Mary had studied English before, she would have passed the exam*
>   (in fact, in reality, Mary didn't study English and thus she didn't pass the exam).

Now, in example 1, we got Past Perfect and in example 2 we also got Past Perfect. The question is that **how we control the tenses** in this following example:

> *If Mary had studied English after she moved to New York, she would have passed the exam*

If saying like that then the *“Mary had studied English after she moved to New York”* breaks the Past Perfect rule because we should say *“Mary studied English after she had moved to New York”*.

But if we say

> *If Mary studied English after she had moved to New York, she would have passed the exam*

then we will break the conditional structure
**If + Past Perfect + Subject + would have + past participle**

I'm not sure if we have to say like this:

> *If Mary had studied English after she had moved to New York, she would have passed the exam*

- **How does a native English speaker express this idea?**
- **Do tenses in conditional sentences have a conflict with the general verb tenses in a sentence?**

Comment: These are two different uses of the past perfect tense, and the conditions that apply to one use don't apply to the other use. There is nothing wrong with *"If Mary had studied English after she moved to New York, she would have passed the exam"*

Comment: Will "*Mary had studied English after she moved to New York*" break the past perfect law?

Comment: Do you mean as its own sentence? I would need to see the context.

Comment: @PeterShor, Yes, in its own sentence. Context: Now is 2016. She moved to NY in 2012, then she studied English in 2013.

Comment: By context, I meant the surrounding sentences. And we really shouldn't answer new questions in comments ... you should ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

These are two different uses of the past perfect tense, and the conditions that apply to one use don't apply to the other use. There is nothing wrong with

> If Mary had studied English after she moved to New York, she would have passed the exam,

and to me it sounds better than either of your alternatives.